# ! LaTeX Error: File `title.sty' not found

Tags: miktex

I have made my own package named title.sty and put it in the folder `F:\packages\tex\latex\titels` and the went to MiKTeX and added `F:\packages\` in the Roots and runed `Refresh FNDB` but I'll still get the error message:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(F:/template_olof_haglund.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
(template_olof_haglund.cls
Document Class: template_olof_haglund 
(D:\MikTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\MikTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo)))

! LaTeX Error: File `title.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Comment: Is that a typo? You say you added F:\packags\ instead of F:\packages\

Comment: Yes it was a typo, sorry

Comment: perhaps you added an (hidden) extension to the file.

Comment: hidden extension?

Comment: Maybe your editor automatically adds an extension, e.g., `.tex`, such that your style file has been stored as `title.sty.tex`. Depending on the settings of your viewer for directories (explorer?) known extensions might be hidden such that you don't even see `.tex`, but just `title.sty`. I guess this was what @UlrikeFischer referred to.